# Merge different JSON inside a single JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, rest, python-requests, request

I am downloading from a rest service JSON file related to shapes, and i can only ask to the server 1000 shapes per time.
What i want to do is to use a cycle to ask the 1000 shapes as a JSON file and then merge at each iteration all the shapes in a single json file. I am doing it by creating a json with the first 1000 requests and then updating it with the other ones. But i am getting lot of troubles. Here is the code:

```
import requests
import json

# URL of the ArcGIS Server Map Service Layer
url = "https://map.sitr.regione.sicilia.it/gis/rest/services/catasto/cartografia_catastale/MapServer/4/query"
# Define the file path and name for the new Geopackage
geopackage_path = 'C:/Users/Daniele/OneDrive/PhD/GIS + ESOM'
n_Items = 8237133
maxitem = 999
# Identify the number of requests
# n_requests = int(n_Items / maxitem)
# Only for test purpose ( To eliminate once code is OK)
n_requests = 10
print ( f"Total number of request is {n_requests}" )

for i in range ( n_requests ):
    lowbound = i * 1000 + 1
    upbound = lowbound + maxitem
    if (n_Items - upbound) < maxitem:
        upbound = n_Items

    # Parameters for the ArcGIS Server Map Service Layer request
    params = {
        "where": f"objectid BETWEEN {lowbound} AND {upbound}",
        "outFields": "*",
        "returnGeometry": "true",
        "f": "json"
    }

    response = requests.get ( url, params = params )

    data = json.loads ( response.text)

    if i == 0:

        with open ( 'data1.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8' ) as f:
            json.dump ( data, f ,ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

    else:
        with open ( 'data1.json', 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8' ) as f:
            file_data=json.load(f)
            file_data.update(data)
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(file_data,f,indent = 4)
```

Comment: What kind of troubles do you have?

Comment: what is the structure of the json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @it-goldman says we have to know the structure of the json. I think this is a JSON array which will be translated into a Python list.
So, you can use any way to [Concatenate Lists in Python](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/concatenate-lists-python)